# How to prevent JsonReaderException when json is not valid in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonconvert

I've a method that deserialize string into a type.

```cs
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestData>("invalid json");
```

If string is not valid, `JsonReaderException` occurring.

I want to return default value of `TestData` (null) when string is not valid instead of throw exception.

How can I do this without `try/catch` and `JObject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `JsonSerializerSettings` to handle it the result of it will be NULL.
The reference of [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_1.htm) and [JsonSerializerSettings.Error](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Error.htm)

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{
    Error = (se, ev) => 
    { 
        ev.ErrorContext.Handled = true; 
    } 
};
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Currency>("invalid json", settings);
```